# brew progress bar rendering wrong

Tags: terminal

When I do `brew install ant` for example I get a progress bar like this:

[image]

It's more a problem when multiple things are installed cause it's easy to miss errors etc. now.

[image]

I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Do you get this problem with the normal macOS Terminal app as well as iTerm? What does `echo $TERM` output? (Try setting `TERM` to `xterm-256color`.)

Comment: Totally going to be terminal settings. We might need you to elaborate a bit on your setup - which version of macOS (to the build, likely - which shell - which application is running) Some settings have changed from the defaults, so this will be a process of elimination to clear for people that can't reproduce this (or haven't learned what they changed to do this)

Comment: It is already `xterm-256color`. I just see that it works fine in the normal terminal. Maybe it's an iterm bug?

Comment: I'm on OSX 10.14.6, on a fresh install, where I did not even restore from a previous backup.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, also. The terminal isn't wide enough. It looks like it's only 76 columns wide. Drag to at least 80. Test using:

```
echo $COLUMNS
```